# Existance of a measure on $\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{Q}}$

Tags: measure-theory

The full question I have is the following: Does there exists a measure $\mu$ on $\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{Q}}$ (Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{Q}$) that satisfies the following:
$$
\mu((a, b]\cap\mathbb{Q}) = b-a 
$$
for all $a\leq b \in \mathbb{R}$. And if it exists, is it unique?

Comment: $\Bbb{Q}$ is countable, so any $\sigma$-additive measure on it is a sum of point masses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Borel σ-Algebra on $\mathbb{Q}$ is generated by open sets in $\mathbb{Q}$, which have the form $(a;b)\cap\mathbb{Q}$ for $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$. Equivalently, it is generated by its closed sets, which are of the form $(a;b)^c\cap\mathbb{Q}$. In particular, singletons; for $x\in\mathbb{Q}$, we have
$$\{x\} = \{x\}\cap\mathbb{Q} = \left[(-\infty;x)\cup(x;+\infty)\right]^c\cap\mathbb{Q}$$
hence $\{x\}\in\mathcal{B}_\mathbb{Q}$.

Now suppose you wanted a measure $μ$ on $\mathcal{B}_\mathbb{Q}$ such that $μ((a;b]\cap\mathbb{Q}) = b-a$.
Taking $b=x\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $a = x-1/n$, we have $μ((x-1/n;x]) = 1/n$. The sets $(x-1/n;x]$ decrease to $\{x\}$, while the RHS $1/n\to 0$. Thus $μ(\{x\}) = 0$, for any $x\in\mathbb{Q}$. 
But since a measure is countably additive and $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable, we have
$$μ(\mathbb{Q}) = μ\left(\bigcup_{x\in\mathbb{Q}} \{x\}\right) = \sum_{x\in\mathbb{Q}} μ(\{x\}) = 0$$
so your measure $μ\equiv 0$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: I edited the post, sorry for this, but I think your argument still holds.

Comment: Yep it holds, you assumed correctly that the set $(a, b]$ is obviously not in $\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{Q}}$.